CopyFiles Task Doesn't Find Files in BinariesDirectory
I have an Azure DevOps pipeline that builds an Android bundle. After the task that builds my app, there are two tasks as below. Log of the first one shows that $(Build.BinariesDirectory) folder contains MyApp.aab and MyApp-Signed.aab. But the second task doesn't find anything and copies 0 files.
Any ideas why it is happening? I've tried everything including hard-coding /Users/runner/work/1/b/MyApp-Signed.aab which is the actual path from log of previous tasks.
- task: Bash@3
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: 'ls'
    workingDirectory: '$(Build.BinariesDirectory)'
  
- task: CopyFiles@2
  inputs:
    Contents: '$(Build.BinariesDirectory)/*.aab'
    TargetFolder: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
    OverWrite: true
    flattenFolders: true


I found the solution. The missing piece was SourceFolder. By default it is set to $(Build.SourcesDirectory) so it couldn't find the .aab files. The working  version is:
- task: CopyFiles@2
  inputs:
    Contents: '*.aab'
    SourceFolder: '$(Build.BinariesDirectory)'
    TargetFolder: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
    OverWrite: true
    flattenFolders: true


Glad to see the issue can be resolved, an thanks for sharing the solution. Maybe, you can accept this answer by yourself. It could be also helpful for other people who are looking for a solution of the similar issues. @Delphi.Boy
